# Amazon Web Service RDS security group - removal of 0.0.0.0/0 blocks my EC2

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address, rds

I am using Amazon Web Service's security group in RDS and want to remove 0.0.0.0/0 - 
I have added all the IPs I want to be able to access my amazon RDS into the RDS security group all in the form of x.x.x.x/32, (including the 2 EC2 instances IP that hosts my webpage), and now I want to remove the 0.0.0.0/0 IP in RDS security group - default group. However, when I remove it it blocks all access to my website (which does communicate with it).

But my question is, shouldn't it still allow the communications between my EC2 and RDS if I have added my EC2 instance public IPs into RDS's security group?

Please help! I cant remove 0.0.0.0/0 without it blocking out all my access although I have all the IPs added correctly!

Comment: Are your instances inside a VPC?

Comment: @DavidLevesque hi, no I dont have VPC. Only using EC2

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a VPC, you need to add the Amazon EC2 security group for the EC2 instance to the DB security group for the DB instance. I don't think it will work with public IPs since these are not used internally. You can find more info and detailed instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.AuthorizingEC2).